# How to serve retina image for responsive below certain browser width?

Tags: html, css, media-queries, retina-display

I am making a one page website that has a centered logo.

I have 4 versions of this logo. Regular size, regular@x2, mobile, mobile@x2.

I figured out how to serve most of the appropriate logos under appropriate circumstances, but cannot figure out how to serve the mobile@x2 version of the logo.

This is the media query codes that I'm using for these logos.

regular@x2:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)
```

mobile:

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

Is there a way to combine the two to create a version that gets served for retina displays when the browser window gets below 767px wide?

Comment: This [**SO Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13744542/1195891) may be of interest to you. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I just decided to serve an SVG version of the logo :) Works well on modern devices and is much more lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 767px), (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 767px)
```

Should work, shouldn't it? Sorry, I don't have a retina display...